# How do I do a long-term button counter in PyQT5?

Tags: python, button, pyqt5, counter

First time using PyQT5 in code and I'm struggling to do a button counter.

```
def setup_gui(self):

        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

        self.setWindowTitle('Interface')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('web.png'))

        self.plot_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.btn_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Yes")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color : red; color: white") 
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.yes) 
        self.yes_counter = 0 

        self.no_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("No") 
        self.no_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color : green; color: white") 
        self.no_btn.clicked.connect(self.no)
        self.no_counter = 0 

        def yes(self): 
        self.yes_counter += 1
        print("Yes") 

    def no(self):
        self.no_counter += 1
        print("No")
```

If I do this, I can't see the counter in the main layout

This does not work. If possible, I would like it to be a long-term counter e.g. not just a one-off when app is open but rather an all-time counter.

```
def no(self):
        self.no_counter += 1
        print("No" + str(self.no_counter))
```

UPDATE

so I figured out that I needed to add this:

```
self.yes_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
self.no_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()

self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.yes_lbl)
self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.no_lbl) 

self.yes_lbl.setText("Yes Count:" + str(self.yes_counter))
self.no_lbl.setText("No Count:" + str(self.no_counter))
```

so this will allow me to see the counter on the mainscreen.
Now I just need to figure out how to ensure it doesn't reset every time I open it.

Comment: Where did you expect to see it?  If you want to display plain text, then you need to add a QStaticText widget to your layout, and you'll need to update the contents when you update the counter.  To make it persist, you'll need to store the current value in a config file somewhere.

Comment: @TimRoberts QStaticText is only used for drawing optimization, is not a widget, so the OP will probably need a QLabel.